# ASCII value related query

Tags: java

I read that **"When an integer is cast into a char, only its lower 16 bits of data are used; the other part is ignored"**. Based on this shouldn't i get the char value for '0041' as output.Instead i get 'A' as output ,which has an ASCII value of 65. Why does this happen??

```
  public class practice {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           char ch = (char)0XAB0041;
           System.out.println(ch);
           char ch1= (char)65.25;
           System.out.println(ch1);
       }
 }
```

Will i get the same output if i myself consider only the lower 16 bits for casting.As below:

```
   char ch = (char)0041;
   System.out.println(ch);
```

**Guys could anyone clear this problem that i am facing in comprehending the relation between unicode,ASCII and hexadecimal values...
Thanks..**

Comment: where did you read that?

Comment: @Thomas Intro to Java Programming 8th Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0XAB0041` in decimal is:

```
11206721
```

in binary, it becomes:

```
101010110000000001000001
```

So taking last 16 bits,
we have: `0000000001000001`=`65` in decimal
If you see the ASCII table in [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) link, it is for 'A'

Hence,  `0XAB0041` on casting to `char`, becomes `'A'`

If you consider

```
   char ch = (char)0041;
   System.out.println(ch);
```

0041 is taken by java as octal literal with decimal value 4*8+1=33.So ASCII code for 33 decimal is !.

Hence the output will be:

```
!
```

Hence if you ask "Will i get the same output if i myself consider only the lower 16 bits for casting.", your answer is !(not) :)

Comment: I realize X in 0XAB0041 stands for hexadecimal. What does the 0 before X and AB after X denote?

Comment: Two errors: (char)0041 is decimal 33, and this is '!'. (char)41 is ')'

Comment: @Dixon the X in 0XAB0041 stands for Hexadecimal literals.Have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Literals/Numeric_Literals/Integer_Literals and scroll down to Integer Literals

Answer (score 4):

`0x0041` is decimal 65 which is ASCII 'A'.

`65.25` would be truncated to 65, so it's still 'A'.

What were you expecting?

Comment: I am a beginner,just got confused between unicode,ASCII and hex.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with `0x41` which is 65(16 * 4 + 1) in decimal system. 'A' corresponds to ascii 0x41.